# NSMutableArray release causes crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

I am using XCode for developing an iPhone app. I am new to this platform and need some help with a particular issue...

I have a method that processes some data and returns two integer values as NSNumber wrapped into a NSMutableArray.

Here is the method:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)processPoints:(int) x:(int) y
 {
 NSMutableArray *mutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
 int x9,y9;

 // ...do some processing...

 NSNumber* xNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:x9];
 NSNumber* yNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:y9];

 [mutArray addObject:xNum];
 [mutArray addObject:yNum];

  return [mutArray autorelease];
 }
```

I call the above method from another method, where I copy the NSNumber stuff into local variables and then release the local copy of NSMutable array.

But the app crashes when releasing this NSMutable array (variable 'mutArray').

Here is the method:

```
-(void)doNinjaAction
 {
   NSMutableArray* mutArray = [self processPoints: x :y];

   NSNumber* s1 = [[mutArray objectAtIndex:0] retain];
   NSNumber* s2 = [[mutArray objectAtIndex:1] retain];

   x = [s1 integerValue];
   y = [s2 integerValue];

   //...proceed with other stuff...

   [mutArray autorelease]; //this is where the system crashes. same for 'release'            
                           //instead of 'autorelease'
  }
```

Can you please explain where I am going wrong with the process of memory release.

My understanding of the process is a bit shaky. Please help.

Comment: It is crashing because you are auto releasing it twice.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're overreleasing the array. You alloc-init it in `processPoints:`, then you autorelease it - that's correct, this is how you dispose of its ownership.

After that, you **don't need to and must not** autorelease or release it once again. This is not `malloc()` from the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

when you call the  statement

```
   NSMutableArray* mutArray = [self processPoints: x :y];
```

This itself acts as autorelease.

Hence releasing the array explicitly will cause the app to crash.

Answer (score 0):

You are releasing mutArray more then once. Once in `processPoints` function and again in `doNinjaAction`.

To resolve the crash remove :

```
[mutArray autorelease];
```

Comment: "Try to print the retain count there so you'll understand where it's going wrong" - [He'll be even more confused if he does that.](http://whentouseretaincount.com)

Comment: You're welcome. Please share this link with whomever wants to give this piece of advice :)

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. Now I get the point... if I do not use the explicit release again, it is working smooth and fine! No memory leaks either... I guess.  Thanks again for all the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSMutableArray *)processPoints:(int) x:(int) y
 {
 NSMutableArray *mutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
 int x9,y9;

 // ...do some processing...

 NSNumber* xNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:x9];
 NSNumber* yNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:y9];

 [mutArray addObject:xNum];
 [mutArray addObject:yNum];

[mutArray autorelase];
  return mutArray;
 }
```

try this one it'll resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSMutableArray *)processPoints:(int) x:(int) y
 {
 NSMutableArray *mutArray =[[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3]autorelease];
 int x9,y9;

 // ...do some processing...

 NSNumber* xNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:x9];
 NSNumber* yNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:y9];

 [mutArray addObject:xNum];
 [mutArray addObject:yNum];

  return mutArray;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

As @H2CO3 and @AppleDelegate suggested, it is right.

Still I would suggest to use ARC and convert your project to ARC enabled.

Go to Edit->Refactor->Convert to Objectiv-C ARC

Then you dont need to do any releases anywhere. It will take care itself of all the releases :)

Comment: who voteeddd it negative may i know man ?? give me the reason